# redirect checked checkbox with php and make it work

Tags: javascript, php

How can i make it work with php code this code, the code is about if you checked will redirect to another website but i want to create checked option with url: https://example.com/index.php?checked1

**First Line of code**

```
if (isset($_GET['checked1'])) {
    $showcheck = 'checked';
}
```

**And javascript code below**  both codes are in one file index.php

```php
<input <?=$showcheck?> type="checkbox" onclick="handleClick(this)">Redirect me after 30s<br>
<script>
  let handleClick = (ele) => {
    if (ele.checked) {
      redirectTime = setTimeout(() => {
        window.location = "/menu.php"
      }, 30000)
    } else if (!ele.checked && typeof redirectTime !== 'undefined') {
      clearTimeout(redirectTime);
    }
  }
</script>
```

with php is not starting redirecting after 30s

Comment: you have to trigger the event "onClick" when the page is loaded

Comment: can i make somehow both "onclick" and  on url

Comment: example: go to https://example.com/index.php?checked1 i don't have to checked the checkbox by myself to redirect after 30s

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?
if (isset($_GET['checked1'])) {
    $showcheck = 'document.getElementById("test").click();';
}
?>

<input type="checkbox" id="test" onclick="handleClick(this)">Redirect me after 30s<br>
<script>
  let handleClick = (ele) => {
    if (ele.checked) {
      redirectTime = setTimeout(() => {
        window.location = "/menu.php"
      }, 30000)
    } else if (!ele.checked && typeof redirectTime !== 'undefined') {
      clearTimeout(redirectTime);
    }
  }

  <?=$showcheck?>  
</script>
```

Comment: is not redirected me after 30s  you are missing \'test\' on  $showcheck = 'document.getElementById(\'test\').click();';

Comment: and the time of 30s is not working on load is redirected me to /menu.php

Comment: It redirects after 30seconds after you load the page, it this what you expect?

Comment: first codes when you presented didn't work, now those works fine ,thanks btw

Answer (score 2):

You've said `window.location = "/"`, which navigates to `/`, not to `/index.php?checked1=anything`.

Comment: i thought i wrote it,  is /menu.php